# Creating an hour in Perl using MySql and the Websocket protocol

Tags: javascript, mysql, perl, websocket

Good afternoon, I'm writing chat in Perl using Mysql and the Websocket protocol.
I am using the AnyEvent module and Protocol :: WebSocket.

I understand that it would be better to use Mojo or Node.js for this, but in my case it needs to be that way.

I receive data from Websocket, reverse and connect. The data entered in the input field also fits into the database.
My problem is that how can I now output this data to the web interface in real time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent;

use AnyEvent::Handle;

use AnyEvent::DBI::MySQL;

use AnyEvent::Socket;
use Protocol::WebSocket::Handshake::Server;

use Protocol::WebSocket::Frame;

my $dbh = AnyEvent::DBI::MySQL->connect("DBI:mysql:chat:localhost", "admin", "admin",
{
    mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
    PrintError => 0,
}) or die;

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $hdl;
my $sth;

AnyEvent::Socket::tcp_server undef, 3000, sub {
    my ($clsock, $host, $port) = @_;

    my $hs    = Protocol::WebSocket::Handshake::Server->new;

    my $frame = Protocol::WebSocket::Frame->new;

    $hdl = AnyEvent::Handle->new(fh => $clsock);

    $hdl->on_read(
        sub {
            my $hdl = shift;

            my $chunk = $hdl->{rbuf};

            $hdl->{rbuf} = undef;            

            if (!$hs->is_done) {
                $hs->parse($chunk);

                if ($hs->is_done) {

                    $hdl->push_write($hs->to_string);
                    return;
                }
            }

            $frame->append($chunk);

            my $message = $frame->next;

            if ($message eq ""){
                $message = undef;
            } else {
                $sth = $dbh->do("INSERT INTO web_chat VALUES('$message')", { async => 0 });
            }

            my $ary_ref = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref("SELECT text FROM web_chat");

        }
    );
};

$cv->wait;

1;
```

Client is not written in Javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<form name="publish">
  <input type="text" name="message" maxlength="50"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<div id="messages"></div>

<script>

let socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.1:3000/websocket/');

// отправка сообщения из формы
document.forms.publish.onsubmit = function() {
  let outgoingMessage = this.message.value;

  socket.send(outgoingMessage);
  return false;
};

socket.onopen = function () {
  console.log("Websocket Connection");
};

socket.onerror = function () {
  console.log("Error websocket connection ");
}

// прослушка входящих сообщений
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  let incomingMessage = event.data;
  showMessage(incomingMessage);
};

socket.onclose = event => console.log(`Closed ${event.code}`);

// отображение информации в div#messages
function showMessage(message) {
  let messageElem = document.createElement('div');
  messageElem.textContent = message;
  document.getElementById('messages').prepend(messageElem);
}

</script>
```

Comment: You should use DBI placeholders. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I googled this documentation, https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::WebSocket::Server

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest Mojolicious and Mojo::Mysql for this?

Protocol::WebSocket is pretty “bare-bones” and doesn’t handle a lot of the protocol details like ping/pong.